# Integrating CoreML model into an iOS Message Filter Extension

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, imessagefilter

I have an iOS `Message Filter App Extension` set-up and I have a CoreML `.mlmodel` file that I want to use in this extension.
The `mlmodel` has a **Target Membership** for both the app, and the app extension.

But when I try to use it from the `ILMessageFilterExtension` class, I am getting the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "initialization of text classifier model with model data failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=initialization of text classifier model with model data failed}
```

This is my code (`MessageClassifier` is my model's generated class name) :

```swift
do {
    let config = MLModelConfiguration()
    let model = try MessageClassifier(configuration: config)
    
    let messageClassifier = MessageClassifierInput(text: message)
    let prediction = try model.prediction(input: messageClassifier)
    
    let classification = MessageClassification(stringLiteral: prediction.label)
    
    return classification.messageFilterAction
} catch {
    logger.log(level: .os, icon: "‼️", "Message classification failure: \(error)")
}
```

Any idea why this could happen? Couldn't find anything online or any permissions I need to add for this.

Comment: Have you verified the model works with `coremltools` or otherwise?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Yes it does. It also works great when implemented within the actual app itself, but not within the App Extension.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Message Extensions, but perhaps this CoreML Message Extension could help: https://github.com/darcwader/DSpam